# Candump Filter is occasionally not working correctly

Tags: bash, can-bus, canutils

For a bash script, where I read information from a Micoboard via can, I use the candump command with a filter to read a specific message.

My problem is that while the filter itself is working correctly, the  candump command with the filter occasionally does not record the specific message on the Can Bus.

I have already verified that the expected  message is being sent, by displaying all can canmessages with candump without the filter.

The code of the bash script to receive the specific can message is displayed here :

```
CAN_PORT="can4"
CAN_ID_GET_VERSION=01500000
CAN_ID_SET_VERSION=01230000
candump -L ${CAN_PORT},${CAN_ID_SET_VERSION}:1ffffff | tee temp_candump.log &
candumpid=$!
cansend ${CAN_PORT} ${CAN_ID_GET_VERSION}#
sleep 0.5 # wait for an answer from microboard
kill $candumpid
cat temp_candump.log
```

This code gives me the expected can message about 9 out of 10 times.
My question is if there is a problem  in the code or has someone else experienced a similar problem and found a solution ?
Any answer would be appreciated.

With kind regards

Comment: Using sleep seems not to be to best way of doing what you want as it doesn't guarantee that you received something. You should instead use the -n <count> option on candump (that terminate the process after receiving <count> frames). Also, you could use the -L option to log directly to a file.

Comment: hi, thanks for your answer. I used sleep as I did not want to endlessly wait for a can messge. The script should not wait for an indefinite amount of time for the answer and should terminate itself after wating for half a second.I also set the sleep time longer to 2 seconds and it stll does not display the expected message

Comment: Are you using the latest version of can-utils?